# ¿Por qué no puedo cambiar el valor de una variable a menos que no este dentro de un método?

Tags: java, java-8

Por ejemplo:

```
public class Controlador {
  int numero = 10;
  // Ahora quiero cambiarle el valor a la variable numero

  numero = 25; // Me sale error

public String Index() { 
 // Alguna accion

 return "variable";
  }
}
```

Pero si estoy dentro del método, sí puedo acceder a la variable numero y cambiarle el valor. Y no entiendo porque se supone que la variable numero esta al inicio de la clase, osea que la puedo ocupa en en cualquier parte.

```
  public class Controlador {
int numero = 10;



 public String Index() { 
 // Ahora cambiaré el valor de la variable
   numero= 20;   // Y si la puedo cambiar, solamente desde un método.

return "variable";
 }
}
```

Es más, de hecho fuera de los métodos no puedo ocupar ni siquiera un System.out.printLine("")
Es como que fuera de los metodos de una clase solamente se pueda instanciar o crear variables, pero no puedes hacer ninguna acción. Si alguien me pudiera explicar por favor.

Comment: No tiene ningún sentido cambiar un valor en la definición de la clase. Si el valor tiene que ser `25` declara de entrada **`int numero = 25;`** y punto. Si el valor debe cambiar después, cámbialo desde un método para encapsular los datos. Y si lo declaras público podrías cambiarlo mediante:  `unaInstaciaDeControlador.numero=25;`  pero esto no es recomendable.

Comment: Sep, sé que no es recomendable. Pero me gustaría saber el por que? como funciona por detrás el hecho de que no pueda hacer nada fuera de los métodos de una Clase, sino que solamente crear variables o crear objetos.

Answer (score 3):

Las clases, como todos los elementos de Java tienen sus reglas.

Para el caso que nos ocupa, [el apartado 8.3 de la especificación de Java, titulado *Field declaration*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3) indica las normas para declarar campos o miembros de una clase:

Dice lo siguiente:

> The variables of a class are introduced by field declarations.
>
> `FieldDeclaration:`
>
> `{FieldModifier} UnannType VariableDeclaratorList ;`

Es decir, los miembros de una clase pueden declararse indicando el `FieldModifier` (`public, private, protected`). Cuando no se pone nada se asume que es `public`. Luego, `UnannType` que sería el tipo, y luego `VariableDeclaratorList` que incluye el identificador de ese objeto y inicialización o no (darle un valor).

Al hacer esto estás obrando de acuerdo a la especificación:

```
int numero = 10;
```

Ese campo es `public`, se identificado como `numero` y es inicializado con un valor `10`.

Significa que para asignar el valor `25` a número, tendrías que volver a cumplir con las mismas normas, haciendo algo así:

```
int numero = 25;
```

Pero esto choca con otra regla definida en la especificación de Java ([mismo apartado 8.3 in fine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3)):

> It is a compile-time error for the body of a class declaration to
> declare two fields with the same name.
>
> ---
>
> Es un error en tiempo de compilación que el cuerpo de una declaración
> de clase declare dos campos con el mismo nombre.

Por tanto, para cambiar el valor de un miembro no se usa el cuerpo de la clase, sino alguno de sus métodos, o si el miembro es accesible, lo puedes modificar directamente por medio de la instancia de la clase.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!  :D  Se puede decir que el cuerpo de la clase solo sirve para instanciar objetos o crear variables, y si quiero instancia despues o cambiar el valor de una variable, se debe hacer en algun método.

Comment: @GabrielGodoyOsses en el caso de tu pregunta no es exactamente para *instanciar* objetos, sino para declarar (e inicializar) un miembro de la clase. En las clases se pueden declarar otros tipos de miembros (métodos, interfaces, otras clases) y campos como es `numero`. [Puedes ver la especificación sobre el cuerpo de las clases en Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.6).

Comment: Y técnicamente (Como trabaja el compilador de java por debajo), por que no se puede hacer nada mas que incicializar o declarar variables fuera de los métodos? Muchas Gracias de vdd por tú ayuda.

Comment: @GabrielGodoyOsses para eso tendrás que adentrarte en la especificación de la JVM (la máquina virtual de Java), allí se explica el funcionamiento interno del lenguaje. Por ejemplo, [puedes leer esto sobre los Campos (Fields)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se16/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.5). En la red también hay muy buenos artículos sobre el tema *Java Virtual Machine Internals* donde se explica el modo de funcionamiento interno de Java. [Este es un ejemplo](https://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JVMInternals.html) de ese tipo de artículos.

Answer (score 0):

**En java existen 3 tipos de variables:**
**Variables de clase**: son variables estáticas que se declaran fuera de cualquier método, constructor o bloque, el cual solo permite almacenar un valor por cada variable, pero si puedes alterar el valor dentro de cualquier método, bloque o constructor (Aunque no es recomendable).

**Variables de instancia**: son variables que no necesariamente pueden ser estáticas pero al igual que las variables de clase se crean fuera de cualquier método. La diferencia es que luego a través de cualquier método podrás llamar dicha variable por una instancia y podrás cambiar su valor si no es estática.

**Variables locales**: estas variables son las más usadas y se crean dentro de cualquier método, constructor o bloque, puedes alterar el valor y su tiempo de vida termina cuando se culmina de ejecutar el método.

Te muestro un ejemplo:

```
public class Principal {
    static int numero = 1;
    int numero_par = 10;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numero_local = 16;
        Principal p = new Principal();
        
        System.out.println("mi variable estática de clase: "+ numero);
        System.out.println("mi variable de clase por instancia sin modificar: "+ p.numero_par);
        p.numero_par = 20;
        System.out.println("mi variable de clase por instancia modificado: "+ p.numero_par);
        System.out.println("mi variable local: "+ numero_local);
    }
}
```

Eso da como resultado:

```
mi variable estática de clase: 1
mi variable de clase por instancia sin modificar: 10
mi variable de clase por instancia modificado: 20
mi variable local: 16
```